# NetServerEnum doesn't find computer

Tags: c#

I am using `NetServerEnum()` to discover computers in my network, the code is from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.netserverenum).

This is how I call the function to get the servers:

```
  var servers = GetServerList(SV_101_TYPES.SV_TYPE_ALL);
```

The function works, but it wont find 1 machine that is connected directly via ethernet cable to my computer. There is no switch or router in between the 2 machines.

I can see the machine if I go to `Network` in Windows.

Why wouldn't `NetServerEnum()` find the machine?

Comment: Without any of your code, it's hard to say. My magic crystalball says this machine is not in your domain. But my crystalball is sometimes wrong.

Comment: Can you try with 0xAFFFFFFF?

Comment: Define what you mean by *connected directly via ethernet cable*, like indirectly through a switch or like directly through a crossover cable?

Comment: @rene thanks, I tried it, but now `GetServerList()` returns no servers at all

Comment: @Lloyd directly via crossover cable